# node-red owfs not working (node-red-contrib-owfs)

Tags: raspberry-pi, node-red

I have one-wire sensors connected to a Raspberry Pi and working with OWFS, and I can access these at localhost:4304 using python ow library, and via the web interface at localhost:2121.

In node-red, I have installed node-red-contrib-owfs and by default it is configured to look for owfs at localhost:4304, but it gives the error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4304`

Does anyone have this working successfully or have an idea of what could be wrong? Everything has been installed and freshly updated today.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, fixed it.
In /etc/owfs.conf, the default configuration has

```
server: port = localhost:4304
```

Changing this to

```
server: port = 4304
```

Means that node-red-contrib-owfs can access it.

Whatever.